# Concatenate columns and adds digits postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation, generate-series, set-returning-functions

Given the table `table1` in PostgreSQL:

```
number1 | number2 | min_length | max_length
40      |  1801   |     8      |     8  
40      |  182    |     8      |     8  
42      |  32     |     6      |     8  
42      |  4      |     6      |     6  
43      |  691    |     9      |     9
```

I want to create new table `table2` like:

```
start        |      stop
4018010000   |      4018019999  
4018200000   |      4018299999  
42320000     |      42329999
423200000    |      423299999
4232000000   |      4232999999
42400000     |      42499999  
43691000000  |      43691999999
```

So the new table will be consisting of:

```
column_1 = a concatenation of old_column_1 + old_column_2 + a number of "0" equal to (old_column_3 - length of the old_column_2)
```

```
column_2 = a concatenation of old_column_1 + old_column_2 + a number of "9" equal to (old_column_3 - length of the old_column_2)
```

And when `min_length` is not equal to `max_length`, I need to take into account all the possible lengths. So for the line "42";"32";6;8 , all the lengths are: 6,7 and 8.

I tried to create the new table2 AS table1, then to create new columns start and stop, then to concatenate the columns 1 and 2 like that:

```
create table table2 as select * from table1;
alter table table2 add column start text,
                   add column stop text;
update table2 set start = number1 || number2
```

For the concatenation of the first 2 columns. But I can't figure out how to do the all concatenation, to add the "0"s and the "9"s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all columns are `NOT NULL`, and `max_length` is always greater than `min_length` this does the job:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
SELECT t.number1::text || rpad(t.number2::text, len, '0') AS start
     , t.number1::text || rpad(t.number2::text, len, '9') AS stop
FROM   table1 t, generate_series(min_length, max_length) len
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8a4ac84e8deb5d394b25905b1a98b5a4)*

The manual for [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) and [`rpad()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER).

If `number1` or `number2` can be `NULL`, throw in [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL):

```
SELECT COALESCE(t.number1::text, '') || rpad(COALESCE(t.number2::text,''), len, '0') AS start
     , COALESCE(t.number1::text, '') || rpad(COALESCE(t.number2::text,''), len, '9') AS stop
FROM table1 t, generate_series(min_length, max_length) len;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5d5c0589157f3c936931ee6e377a11f5)*

If `min_length` or `max_length` can be `NULL`, you'll have to define what's supposed to happen.

Comment: thanks. But I do have some fields that are null. For example, if I have on the column "number2" an empty field, that case will not be treated in the table 2 and I will lose the data for that specific field. Is there any solution for this case ?

Comment: @Savas31: That's why you should lead with a table definition in the question. Fix with `COALESCE`.

Comment: thnks, i tried CREATE TABLE table3 AS SELECT t.number1::text || rpad(COALESCE(t.number2::text,''), len, '0') AS start, t.number1::text || rpad(COALESCE(t.number2::text,''), len, '9') AS stop FROM table1 t , generate_series(min_length, max_length) len;
but the result is the same.